# Monitoring the progress of specified pods with oc cli

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I want to know is there a way to monitor the progress of a particular pod instead of seeing all pods?

For example I scale consleapp

```
oc scale dc consleapp --replicas=3
```

After that command I want to watch the progress of only consoleapp and ensure the pods are active.
I thought you'd be able to run this command
`oc get pods consoleapp -watch` but it does not work. Is there a way for me to monitor the progress of this? very similar to `oc rollout status deploymentconfig/consoleapp --watch` but without rolling out a new deployment.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `oc get pods consoleapp`, you're asking for a pod named `consoleapp`, which of course doesn't exist. If you want to watch all the pods managed by the DeploymentConfig, you can use the `--selector` (`-l`) option to select pods that match the `selector` in your DeploymentConfig.

If you have:

```
spec:
  selector:
    name: consoleapp
```

Then you would run:

```
oc get pod -l name=consoleapp -w
```

If your `selector` has multiple labels, combine them with commas:

```
oc get pod -l app=consoleapp,component=frontend -w
```

---

NB: DeploymentConfigs are considered deprecated and can generally be replaced by standard Kubernetes Deployments:

> Both Kubernetes Deployment objects and OpenShift Container Platform-provided DeploymentConfig objects are supported in OpenShift Container Platform; however, it is recommended to use Deployment objects unless you need a specific feature or behavior provided by DeploymentConfig objects.

(from "[Understanding Deployment and DeploymentConfig objects](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/applications/deployments/what-deployments-are.html)")